# Why does this regular expression fail in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Take a look at this test method:

```
[ Test ]
public static void TestRegex() {
    var goodTextsToTest = new List<string>
        {
            "http://google.com",
            "https://google.com/",
            "ftp://bugger!!!one1",
            "ftss://shoot",
            "somelongergibberish://flkjd",
            "thescheme://green"
        };
    var badTextsToTest = new List<string> { "bad432:4h//orange", "1ftp://1bugger!!!one1", "IAmTheVeryModelOfAModernMajorGeneral", "" };

    var regex = new Regex( "^([a-z][a-z0-9+\\.\\-]*)*://", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );

    foreach( var txt in badTextsToTest )
        Assert.IsFalse( regex.IsMatch( txt ), "Passed but should have failed: " + txt );

    foreach( var txt in goodTextsToTest )
        Assert.IsTrue( regex.IsMatch( txt ), "Failed but should have passed: " + txt );
}
```

As it is currently written, this code never returns from `var regex = new Regex( "^([a-z][a-z0-9+\\.\\-]*)*://", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );`. The input the code gets stuck on is "IAmTheVeryModelOfAModernMajorGeneral".

**Why does this regular expression cause an infinite loop when the input is "IAmTheVeryModelOfAModernMajorGeneral" ?**

Bonus question:
This code *does* finish executing if you remove "://" from the regular expression. I.e. `var regex = new Regex( "^([a-z][a-z0-9+\\.\\-]*)*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );` **Why does this fix it?**

Comment: Let's not focus on the intention of the regular expression or how it can be better. Just how this particular expression fails with this particular input.

Comment: @Thomas: slashes are not special characters.

Comment: catastrophic backtracking?

Comment: How does it perform on the string `IveInformationVegetableAnimalAndMineral`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex, designed as it is now will take more than 87500 steps to complete, because of backtracking. See the debbuger [here](https://regex101.com/r/zE8uC7/1). This is what we call [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Some languages will run forever, some other will throw a stack overflow...

Comment: Or runtimes. 4.5.2 added tail recursion optimizations that reuse a stack if the recursion call is last, so never result in stack overflows. I suspect any language/runtime optimized for functional programming will behave the same